# Fan-gating in a facebook iframe tab using anything else put PHP

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-page

I need to make a tab on Facebook that show one content to vistors who don't like the page the tab is shown on, and another conent to those who does. I know that it can be done using PHP, my question is: Can it be done using javascript.
It need to work just like it used to do using fbml.

Comment: This might help you,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340678/fan-gate-like-gate-show-to-connections-with-javascript-and-like-box

Answer (score 0):

Using php is the easiest way to "fan-gate" your content which doesn't need any permission. I never tried getting signed request thru Javascript SDK but this one might help you:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getAuthResponse/